# RSA C# ImportParameters "The parameter is incorrect" exception

Tags: c#, exception, encryption, cryptography, rsa

I have a server (python) and a client (c#), I need to communicate between them temporarily using assymetric rsa cryptography. 
When I connect to the server as the client, I send him my public key and he send me his. I use at the server the rsa library and I get there the server's public key parameters {n,e} I send those and receive them with a space between them. I seperate them and convert the modulus into a BigInteger using this function:

```
public static BigInteger GetBigInteger(string number)
{
    BigInteger bigNum = new BigInteger();
    for (int i = number.Length; i > 0; i--)
    {
        bigNum *= 10;
        bigNum += (int) number[number.Length-i];
    }
    return bigNum;
}

public static void Connect(IPAddress ipAddress, int port)
{
    try
    {                
        string[] message;
        byte[] data = new byte[1024];
        srvr.Receive(data); //Recieve the server's public key. 
        int length = int.Parse(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data.Take(4).ToArray()));
        message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data.Skip(4).Take(length).ToArray()).Split(' ') ;
        RSACryptoServiceProvider RSAserver = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(1024);
        RSAParameters par = new RSAParameters();
        par.Modulus = GetBigInteger(message[0]).ToByteArray();  // Saves the server's public key.
        par.Exponent = new byte[] { 1, 0, 1 }; // Saves the server's public key.           
        RSAserver.ImportParameters(par);
        addresseeKey = RSAserver.ToXmlString(false);
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

An exception is thrown on the ImportParameters line that says: "The parameter is incorrect" .
What's wrong?

Comment: You should reduce your code to a minimal example. You don't need sockets for that. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also see [Cryptographic Interoperability: Keys](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25487/Cryptographic-Interoperability-Keys) on The Code Project. It gives a number of examples of *"The parameter is incorrect"*, and the fixes for it.

Answer (score 0):

BigInteger.ToByteArray() exports the data in little-endian order.  RSAParameters wants all of its data in big-endian order.

There's also an issue that the modulus value should have its most significant bit set, and therefore BigInteger.ToByteArray() needs to add in a padding byte to prevent the number from being reinterpreted as being negative, so you'll need to trim that off.

Assuming that your python export is representing the modulus as a base-10 positive integer, your code will work (though [BigInteger.Parse(string)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268231(v=vs.110).aspx) would be more efficient) once you align the data properly.

```
byte[] tmp = GetBigInteger(message[0]).ToByteArray();

// Array.Resize (to a smaller number) trims off the high index values,
// so it's slightly more compact code to do this before the resize.
if (tmp.Length > 0 && tmp[tmp.Length-1] == 0)
    Array.Resize(ref tmp, tmp.Length - 1);

Array.Reverse(tmp);
par.Modulus = tmp;
```

Comment: I've suspected that this is the problem, but, the byte array as it is is one byte longer than that the RSAParameters accepts. 129 bytes instead of 128. Might it be that the little-endian order adds a byte 0 at the end of it?
And if so, that byte disappear in the big endian and it will be ok?

Comment: Ah, yes, the sign padding byte.  Updated the snippet.